# Sklearn Random Forest Regressor has all the same predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I am trying to build a Random Forest Regressor for about 6 million data values stored in a data frame. However, when I run my code, all the predicted values come out as the same value, which is impossible. Also, I have run the same code on multiple different computers and it works for one but not the others. I am not sure what is going on.
I think that it is not fitting the data, which is making the predictions all the same, but I don't know how to fix it.

I am running the regressor on this dataframe (It's formatted a little weirdly on here)

```
1-M_AE_nT   SYM/H_INDEX_nT  Sec CLat    SLat    SLon    Height  STime   DipLat  MagLon  ... DenUncertainty  NuminBin    NuminBinThrusters   AveDragCoef year    month   day hour    minute  second
1   250.0   -10.0   20.0    -27.0   -26.01869   91.17059    485.397 6.0800  -37.49094   159.49559   ... 2.525557e-14    3.0 0.0 2.985   2003    10  1   0   1   0
2   267.0   -10.0   70.0    -30.0   -29.21327   91.03207    486.025 6.0846  -40.90827   158.48730   ... 2.581399e-14    5.0 0.0 2.997   2003    10  1   0   2   0
3   268.0   -10.0   142.5   -33.0   -33.84216   90.83946    487.036 6.0919  -45.80439   156.77887   ... 2.583156e-14    4.0 0.0 3.022   2003    10  1   0   3   0
4   259.0   -10.0   212.5   -39.0   -38.30748   90.66537    488.104 6.0998  -50.44992   154.80710   ... 2.503691e-14    6.0 3.0 3.043   2003    10  1   0   4   0
5   252.0   -10.0   287.5   -42.0   -43.08716   90.49610    489.312 6.1093  -55.31874   152.26286   ... 2.665537e-14    2.0 2.0 3.066   2003    10  1   0   5   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
87835   391.0   -22.0   86055.0 -60.0   -59.68290   25.61019    514.969 1.6079  -58.43060   73.24151    ... 3.849055e-14    7.0 0.0 3.190   2003    11  30  23  55  0
87836   377.0   -22.0   86155.0 -66.0   -65.98446   25.71737    516.534 1.6428  -62.40535   67.35048    ... 4.443331e-14    9.0 0.0 3.247   2003    11  30  23  56  0
87837   351.0   -22.0   86202.5 -69.0   -68.97452   25.87007    517.088 1.6662  -64.30795   64.06817    ... 4.598777e-14    10.0    0.0 3.274   2003    11  30  23  57  0
87838   337.0   -22.0   86250.0 -72.0   -71.96241   26.13300    517.510 1.6969  -66.20866   60.33311    ... 4.745023e-14    9.0 0.0 3.304   2003    11  30  23  58  0
87839   319.0   -22.0   86297.5 -75.0   -74.94779   26.57178    517.795 1.7394  -68.08806   56.00031    ... 4.916760e-14    10.0    0.0 3.336   2003    11  30  23  59  0
87684 rows × 25 columns
```

with this code

```
target = np.array(merged_df["400kmDensity"])
merged_df = merged_df.drop("400kmDensity", axis = 1)

features_list = list(merged_df.columns)

#df = np.array(merged_df)

#Set training and testing groups
train_features, test_features, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(merged_df, target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 16)

#Train model

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 150, random_state = 16)
rf.fit(train_features, train_target)

#Make predictions and calculate error
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
print(predictions)
```

And this is what the predictions return

```
array([3.43048358e-12, 3.43048358e-12, 3.43048358e-12, ...,
       3.43048358e-12, 3.43048358e-12, 3.43048358e-12])
```